# FFmpeg destroys my Images

Tags: image, ffmpeg

Rightnow iam trying to render a Video reading my image Folder with about 83 Images. Iam using this FFMPEG Snip:

```
 ffmpeg -f image2   -i images/*.jpg  -b 450k -r 30  zoom100.avi  2>&1
```

But iam really frustrated, FFMPEG always replace all my Images with the first Image. And The video it also creates me is about 2 Frames long
Here the FFMPEF Feedback

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:26:50 with gcc 4.6.3
The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed
in a future release. It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for
incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv
(see Changelog for details). Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, image2, from 'images/0750.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x1280 [PAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[buffer @ 0x24a4220] w:1280 h:1280 pixfmt:yuvj420p
[buffer @ 0x24a4a00] w:1280 h:1280 pixfmt:yuvj420p
[buffer @ 0x24a52c0] w:1280 h:1280 pixfmt:yuvj420p
[buffer @ 0x24a5b20] w:1280 h:1280 pixfmt:yuvj420p
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....

[buffer @ 0x24d4320] w:1280 h:1280 pixfmt:yuvj420p
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj420p' for codec 'mpeg4', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
[buffer @ 0x24d03c0] w:1280 h:1280 pixfmt:yuvj420p
[avsink @ 0x24ceea0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0x24cc460] w:1280 h:1280 fmt:yuvj420p -> w:1280 h:1280 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Output #0, image2, to 'images/0751.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x1280 [PAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Output #1, image2, to 'images/0752.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #1.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x1280 [PAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Output #2, image2, to 'images/0753.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #2.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x1280 [PAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
Output #82, image2, to 'images/0833.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #82.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x1280 [PAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Output #83, avi, to 'zoom100.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #83.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1280x1280 [PAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 450 kb/s, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #1.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #2.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #3.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #4.0
    ....
    ....

  Stream #0.0 -> #80.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #81.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #82.0
  Stream #0.0 -> #83.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=    1 fps=  0 q=7.0 Lq=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=7.0 q=6.5 size=      -0kB time=0.03 bitrate=  -5.3kbits/s    
video:16698kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000129%
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `*` alone without using `-pattern_type glob`: otherwise it will assume the first image is the only input and the rest are outputs. This is especially dangerous if using `-y` because it will overwrite the input images without asking you.

## Glob pattern

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i "images/*.jpg" output
```

Probably not supported on Windows.

## Sequence pattern

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i images/%04d.png output
```

Assumes your input are named `0001.png`, `0002.png`, `0003.png`, etc.

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg image file demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1)

Comment: All your solutions i tried before, and all failed. Allways:  "images/%04d.jpg: No such file or directory." 
If i try other Jpeg's it works. For some reason ffmpeg doesnt accept these jpegs which i created before with imagick. Ok anyway. Thanks .Is there a  trusty OS which works fine with FFMPEG?

Comment: @dazzafact I can't provide much help without seeing the directory contents, your command, and the complete console output. `ffmpeg` works on just about any OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -f image2   -i images/%04d.jpg  -b 450k -r 30  zoom100.avi
```

Otherwise the shell expands it where the first image is an input file, and the others are outputs. This way, they're all input files.